# Deep Learning Sample app of Accord.NET build errors

Tags: neural-network, accord.net

I downloaded the Accord.net framework and installed the packages Accord, Accord.MachineLearning, Accord.Controls, and Accord.Neuro, then I tried to build the Deep Learning sample app, but I keep getting these errors:

> The type or namespace name 'ResizeNearestNeighbor' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   framework-development\Samples\Neuro\Deep
>   Learning\Controls\DrawingCanvas.xaml.cs   58
>
> The type or namespace name 'ActivationNetwork' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   framework-development\Samples\Neuro\Deep
>   Learning\Controls\NetworkDiagram.xaml.cs  33
>
> The type or namespace name 'ActivationLayer' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   framework-development\Samples\Neuro\Deep
>   Learning\Controls\NetworkLayer.xaml.cs    31

When browsing the source code (framework-development\Sources\Accord.Neuro\AForge\Layers), I can see all of these classes (ActivationLayer, ActivationNetwork, etc) defined. But they don't seem to be in the assemblies.

What Am I missing?